# scanf_s string with spaces in between

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets, spaces

```
void del() {
int temp = checker;
char search[30];
printf("Please enter the book name to be removed : ");
scanf_s("%[^\n]s", search, 30);
//fgets(search, 30, stdin);
for (int i = 0; i < checker; i++) {
    if (strcmp(search, bookshelf[i].name) == 0) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < checker; j++) {
            strcpy_s(bookshelf[i].name, 31, bookshelf[j].name);
            strcpy_s(bookshelf[i].semi_ISBN, 5, bookshelf[j].semi_ISBN);
            bookshelf[i].page = bookshelf[j].page;
            i++;
        }
        checker--;
        printf("%s is removed from your bookshelf.\n\n", search);
    }
}
if(temp==checker)
    printf("%s is not in your bookshelf.\n\n", search);
```

}

this is my code, and for some reason, when I try to use either the scanf_s or fgets, the result shown is:
"Please enter the book name to be removed : 儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆 is not in your bookshelf."
as soon as I run the function (did not type anything).

What could be wrong..?

Comment: You didn't check the return value from `scanf_s`. Also, `"%[^\n]s"` is wrong (why is there an `s` in there?).

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of the other 100 "scanf skips input", "my program doesn't wait for fgets", etc questions. I can't say for certain because you didn't post a [mcve]. The usual problem is using `scanf` for user input, though. If you do all input through `fgets`, the issue doesn't arise.

Comment: **"as soon as I run the function (did not type anything)."** means that you have left characters unread in `stdin` from previous inputs your program has taken. Remember it is your responsibility to account for any characters that remain unread in your input buffer *after every input*. Before your input with `scanf_s` above add `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();` (and always, always check the return from `scanf` every time -- you must validate every user input, that starts by examining the `return` and then empty any chars that remain in `stdin`)